# Is there a solution for the PMD warning about log.error

Tags: java, apache, logging

I am using PMD tool in eclipse for reviewing code.I am unable to find a solution for the warning message "There is log block surrounded by if "  for the line of code - >`log.error("exception "+e);`
However the same warning message goes away for log.info when i write `if(log.isInfoEnabled())`
log.info("notification ");
How can we fix the issue for log.error? It doesn't accept below code :

```
if(log.isInfoEnabled())
log.error("exception "+e);
```

Anybody have come across same issue and found a solution please advice.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you check if info is enabled before logging an error?

Comment: Well then why does PMD report it as a warning ?

Comment: Probably because the code is atypical. That's why I'm asking for clarification; I could see checking if error is enabled before logging an error, but why check info if you're going to log an error?

Comment: Right, but there is no method like log.isErrorEnabled() , so i just tried with log.isInfoEnabled(), How can we solve this?

Comment: What logging framework are you using? From the tags I'd assume (perhaps wrongly) log4j2, which does have a [`Logger.isErrorEnabled()`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html#isErrorEnabled--) method. Also, many logging frameworks provide logging methods that accept a functional interface that supplies the message only if the level is enabled; you could use this if you're trying to avoid the string concatenation when unnecessary.

Comment: If you're using log4j (version 1) then take a look at [`isEnabledFor`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#isEnabledFor(org.apache.log4j.Priority)).

Comment: @Slaw, I am using apache log4j version 1, What is the advantage of using log4j version 2 ? And yeah i see the method isEnabedFor(Priority level) but what should be the priority level value to be set as prameter if i am writing code as below  if(log.isEnabledFor(?)) log.error("exception "+e);

Comment: You'd use `isEnabledFor(Level.ERROR)` (note `Level` is a subclass of `Priority`). As for why you'd use log4j2, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019585/log4j2-why-would-you-use-it-over-log4j and https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/manual/index.html

Comment: Hi Slaw, I changed the code to below,But still PMD is warning "There is log block not surrounded by if"                        `if(log.isEnabledFor(Level.ERROR)){
 log.error("Exc "+e);
}`                   Please help how can i get rid of this warning.